# Python PYPDF2 : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 395: invalid start byte

Tags: nlp, nltk, pypdf

I'm using a tutorial to create a corpus of pdf files. I have the following code:

```
import nltk
import PyPDF2
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def getTextPDF(pdfFileName):
pdf_file = open(pdfFileName, 'rb')
readpdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
text = []
for i in range(0,readpdf.getNumPages()):
    text.append(readpdf.getPage(i).extractText())
return '\n'.join(text)

corpusDir = 'reports/'

jun15 = getTextPDF('reports/June2015.pdf')
dec15 = getTextPDF('reports/December2015.pdf')
jun16 = getTextPDF('reports/June2016.pdf')
dec16 = getTextPDF('reports/December2016.pdf')
jun17 = getTextPDF('reports/June2017.pdf')
dec17 = getTextPDF('reports/December2017.pdf')

files = [jun15,dec15,jun16,dec16,jun17,dec17]
for idx, f in enumerate(files):
    with open (corpusDir+str(idx)+'.txt','w') as output:
        output.write(f)

corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusDir, '.*')

print (corpus.words())
```

> ---
>
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 print (corpus.words())
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/collections.py in
>   **repr**(self)
>       224         pieces = []
>       225         length = 5
>   --> 226         for elt in self:
>       227             pieces.append(repr(elt))
>       228             length += len(pieces[-1]) + 2
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py in
>   iterate_from(self, start_tok)
>       400 
>       401             # Get everything we can from this piece.
>   --> 402             for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):
>       403                 yield tok
>       404
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py in
>   iterate_from(self, start_tok)
>       294             self._current_toknum = toknum
>       295             self._current_blocknum = block_index
>   --> 296             tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
>       297             assert isinstance(tokens, (tuple, list, AbstractLazySequence)), (
>       298                 'block reader %s() should return list or tuple.' %
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py
>   in _read_word_block(self, stream)
>       120         words = []
>       121         for i in range(20): # Read 20 lines at a time.
>   --> 122             words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
>       123         return words
>       124
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py in readline(self,
>   size)    1166         while True:    1167             startpos =
>   self.stream.tell() - len(self.bytebuffer)
>   -> 1168             new_chars = self._read(readsize)    1169     1170             # If we're at a '\r', then read one extra character, since
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py in _read(self,
>   size)    1398     1399         # Decode the bytes into unicode
>   characters
>   -> 1400         chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)    1401     1402         # If we got bytes but couldn't decode any, then
>   read further.
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py in
>   _incr_decode(self, bytes)    1429         while True:    1430             try:
>   -> 1431                 return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')    1432             except UnicodeDecodeError as exc:    1433                 # If the
>   exception occurs at the end of the string,
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py in decode(input, errors)
>        14 
>        15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
>   ---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
>        17 
>        18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position
>   395: invalid start byte

I've been looking at different posts, but I still can't tell if the problem is that I'm using the wrong methods or that I have to encode or decode something. Ifd it's the latter I don't know where. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to see the whole error message but I'm guessing you are using python 2 and your reports have some utf-8 in them. First of, try to specify the encoding at the beginning and when you open your files:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*- 
import nltk
import PyPDF2
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import codecs
def getTextPDF(pdfFileName):
    pdf_file = codecs.open(pdfFileName, 'rb', encoding='utf8')
    readpdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    text = []
    for i in range(0,readpdf.getNumPages()):
        text.append(readpdf.getPage(i).extractText())
    return '\n'.join(text)

corpusDir = 'reports/'

jun15 = getTextPDF('reports/June2015.pdf')
dec15 = getTextPDF('reports/December2015.pdf')
jun16 = getTextPDF('reports/June2016.pdf')
dec16 = getTextPDF('reports/December2016.pdf')
jun17 = getTextPDF('reports/June2017.pdf')
dec17 = getTextPDF('reports/December2017.pdf')

files = [jun15,dec15,jun16,dec16,jun17,dec17]
for idx, f in enumerate(files):
    with codecs.open(corpusDir+str(idx)+'.txt','w', encoding='utf8') as output:
        output.write(f)

corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusDir, '.*')

print (corpus.words())
```

if that doen't work, you can try bodging your strings, but it's not ideal:

```
def toUtf8(stringOrUnicode):
    '''
    Returns the argument in utf-8 encoding
    '''
    typeArg = type(stringOrUnicode)
    if typeArg is unicode:
        return stringOrUnicode.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')
    elif typeArg is str:
        return stringOrUnicode.decode('utf8')
```

Otherwise, show us the message error to try and detect exactly where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first suggestion you gave me but now I'm getting "TypeError: must be str, not bytes" when I try to use the getTextPDF method.